# why it is not giving me the output of maximum?

Tags: r

I want maximum values from the dataframe `data1` from 2 columns out of 4

```
for(i in data1){print(
  c(as.factor(max(data1[,1]))
,as.numeric(max(data1[,3]))  
    ))}
```

Where column 1 is for `name` and column 3 is for `salary`

Comment: PLEASE DON'T USE ALL CAPS - IT LOOKS RUDE. Could you please show a few rows of sample data and your desired result? Are you looking for the name and value of the maximum salary? `max(data1[,1])` will give the maximum of the first column. If the first column is `name`, I assume it isn't numeric, so the maximum will be what is alphabetically last. Also, why the `for` loop? Do you want more than one maximum?

Comment: My best guess as to what you want is `data1[which.max(data1[[3]]), c(1, 3)]`, but it's hard to tell for sure...

Comment: Thank you, Sir, for responding. I wanted to pick the maximum salary( from the salary column) with the employee name (from the name column ) of the database (data1). I used this and it worked. 
`msalary<-function(data1) {
print(paste( "Name=" ,max(data1$Name ) ,"MaxSalary=", max(data1$Salary)))} msalary(data1) `

and I am sorry for using CAPS I did not intend to it was my first question I'll be more care full from next time. – – R

Comment: @GregorThomas is right. Please don't use CAPS as well as provide all relative code because [it's really hard to answer a programming question without code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: trying to make some sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using dplyr you could do like so, switching the data `mtcars` for your own, and the columns `cyl` and `mpg` to `salary` and `name`

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
mtcars %>% 
  filter(mpg == max(mpg)) %>% 
  select(cyl, mpg)
#>                cyl  mpg
#> Toyota Corolla   4 33.9
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>